# Replacing items in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
menu = [{"food": "basic lasagna", "description": "basic lasagna takes tomato sauce and ground beef ."}, {"food": "carbonara pasta", "description": "there are many types of pasta in this world, but carbonara pasta is one of the best ."}, {...}, ...]
```

I have to highlight the food in the description with tags `<food> food </food>`, but I don't know how to do this without complicating with indexes. My initial idea was:

```
for item in menu:
    tag = item["food"]
    if item["food"] in item["description"]:
        i = tag.index()
        tagging = "<food> " + tag + "</food>"
```

But then I got stuck because I don't really know how to replace the item.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what you're after can be done with the `replace` method:

```
import json
menu = [{"food": "basic lasagna", "description": "basic lasagna takes tomato sauce and ground beef ."}, {"food": "carbonara pasta", "description": "there are many types of pasta in this world, but carbonara pasta is one of the best ."}]

for item in menu:
    item["description"] = item["description"].replace(item['food'], "<food>" + item['food'] + "</food>")

print(json.dumps(menu, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "food": "basic lasagna",
        "description": "<food>basic lasagna</food> takes tomato sauce and ground beef ."
    },
    {
        "food": "carbonara pasta",
        "description": "there are many types of pasta in this world, but <food>carbonara pasta</food> is one of the best ."
    }
]
```